# Android Listivew: is asyntask needed when filtering large amount of data/

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-asynctask

Using the Filter widget, if I have a large amount of data for listview, do i need to wrap it inside the Asynctask for performance sake?

If so, could someone provide an example please.

thanks,

Comment: can you please post some code what you have try till ?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion if the date is too huge to execute, i suggest you to put it in a nested asynctask so the app can still run in parallel execution then after the asynctask just update the listview content :)